# define .env file except default env file in react app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I need to load for each development/production server a different .env file.

```
localhost           | .env.localhost
development         | .env.development
production          | .env.production
```

base on react documentation, by default we can use .env.development and .env.production

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

but i want to use new environment variable as localhost. how can i do that? i want to run one of my script by .env.localhost variable's file.

Comment: thanks, but i want to set different variable for development environment of one of my script in addition to start script that have development environment that we set variable of this env in .env.development.

Comment: Do you need to use `.env.localhost`? Because `.env.local` is supported out-of-the-box with create-react-app.

Comment: yes localhost or for example .env.staging

Answer (score 0):

you can modify script part of package.json from:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

for Linux and MacOS to:

```
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

Windows to:

```
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

And if you want to set new variables in environment. Then add then in .env files of shell, but start name with REACT_APP for ex

REACT_APP_MY_VAR

Comment: i want to load environment variable from file name is .env.localhost in one of my scripts not that u say dear Rajender.

Comment: Then I think, you are need this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-env